# Get Particular Inline from the caret position in a paragraph

Tags: wpf, richtextbox, inline, caret, paragraph

I have a paragraph in rich text box where i need to retrieve the particular inline from the caret position.For E.g if the Paragraph has 5 In lines then i need to know in which inline the cursor is now and i want to retrieve that particular inline alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
TextPointer caretPos = rtb.CaretPosition;
TextPointer startText = caretPos.GetLineStartPosition(0);
TextPointer endText = (caretPos.GetLineStartPosition(1) != null ? caretPos.GetLineStartPosition(1) : caretPos.DocumentEnd);
TextRange tr = new TextRange(startText, endText);
```

In tr you will find your line.

If you are loading the Xml from a file you will probably have only one Inline, instead if you are creating the document from code and you are creating the inlines yourself you can do:

```
TextPointer caretPos = rtb.CaretPosition;
Inline inline = caretPos.Parent;
```